# Como colocar um button com posição estática sobre a scrollview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Saudações caros Desenvolvedores.
Tenho uma empty activity com toda a tela ocupada por uma scrollview contendo apenas imageviews e preciso que ela tenha no topo da tela um botão com posição fixa independentemente do scroll, e que abra um menu listado

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, é só deixar esse botão por fora do scroll

Comment: Obrigado Murillo, realmente já foi um avanço para mim mas eu gostaria que esse botão esteja visível por cima das imagens que estão no scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deixarei 2 métodos aqui

O primeiro utilizando o Layout com LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <!--Aqui você coloca suas imagens-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Resultado 1]

O segundo utilizando o Layout com ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <!-- Aqui você coloca suas imagens-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Resultado2]

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente Murillo, meus agradecimentos